# How to replace cropped rectangle in opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have managed to cropped a bounding box with text, e.g. given this image:

[image]

I'm able to exact the following box:

[image]

with this code:

```
import re
import shutil

from IPython.display import Image

import requests
import pytesseract, cv2

"""https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-detection-and-extraction-using-opencv-and-ocr/"""
# Preprocessing the image starts
# Convert the image to gray scale
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Performing OTSU threshold
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Specify structure shape and kernel size.
# Kernel size increases or decreases the area
# of the rectangle to be detected.
# A smaller value like (10, 10) will detect
# each word instead of a sentence.
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (18, 18))

# Applying dilation on the threshold image
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 1)

# Finding contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Creating a copy of image
im2 = img.copy()


for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    # Drawing a rectangle on copied image
    rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # Cropping the text block for giving input to OCR
    cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    
cv2.imwrite('image-notxt.png', cropped)
Image(filename='image-notxt.png',  width=200)
```

Part 1: **How do I replace the cropped box and put back a clear text box?** e.g. to get something like:

[image]

I've tried:

```
    for cnt in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        # Drawing a rectangle on copied image
        rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # Cropping the text block for giving input to OCR
        cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped).strip('\x0c').strip()
        text = re.sub(' +', ' ', text.replace('\n', ' ')).strip()
        if text:
            # White out the cropped box.
            cropped.fill(255)
            # Create the image with the translation.
            cv2.putText(img=cropped, text="foobar", org=(12, 15), fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, fontScale=0.3, color=(0, 0, 0),thickness=1)
            cv2.imwrite('image-notxt.png', cropped)
            Image(filename='image-notxt.png',  width=200)
```

That managed to white out the cropped box and insert the text like this:

[image]

Part 2: **How to create an opencv textbox rectangle with the same size as the cropped box?** e.g. given a string `foobar`, how to get the final image like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you think you would do that? What has your research suggested? Have you found any methods in OpenCV that would allow you to draw a rectangle, or to put text in an image?

Comment: you already did `cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w]`, now you need to do the opposite. you can figure it out.

Comment: Any pointers to any doc would be good, there's just too many noise on opencv that googling didn't help at all.

Comment: Okay managed to get what I want from https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/image-translate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python/OpenCV/Numpy, use Numpy to write a color to the area in the format:

```
img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = color tuple
```

For example:

[image]

```
# Part 1 --- Blank Area

# read image
photo = cv2.imread('Wurst.png')

# define region arguments
x,y,w,h = 40,40,150,45

# blank area
result1 = photo.copy()
result1[40:40+45, 40:40+150] = (255,255,255)

# save results
cv2.imwrite("Wurst_blank_result.png", result1)

# show the results
cv2.imshow("blanked result", result1)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Part 2 --- Write text

# define text arguments
text = "FOOBAR"
thickness = 2
scale = .8
pad = 2

# determine size for text image
(wd, ht), baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(text, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, thickness)
print (wd, ht, baseLine)

# add black text to white background image padded all around
th = ht + 2 * pad
tw = wd + 2 * pad
text_img = np.full((th,tw,3), (255,255,255), dtype=np.uint8)
text_img = cv2.putText(text_img, text, (pad,ht+pad), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, (0,0,0), thickness)
print(text_img.shape)

# insert text image into region of photo
if w>=tw and h>=th:
    # compute offset
    offx = int((w-tw)/2)
    offy = int((h-th)/2)
    # combine the text with the image
    result2 = result1.copy()
    result2[y+offy:y+offy+th, x+offx:x+offx+tw] = text_img
    # save results
    cv2.imwrite("Wurst_text_result.png", result2)
    # show the results
    cv2.imshow("text image", text_img)
    cv2.imshow("text result", result2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
else:
    print("Text Is Too Large")
```

[image]

See cv2.getTextSize() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga3d2abfcb995fd2db908c8288199dba82 and cv2.putText() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576

Comment: He had 2 questions. I answered the first. I have added a note now in my answer to use cv2.putText() to add text in the box

Comment: Thanks @fmw42, your answers makes me less insane in wonder why the cv2 objects don't work the same way as I would normally expect Python would, e.g. changes `cv2.*(img, ...)` functions makes changes inplace, so I had to make copies before "operating" on it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included a copy `img2 = img.copy()` and done the  coloring on img2. Yes, you have to watch out for those functions that do in-place operations and do copies first.

Comment: I have posted code, now, to include the writing of text into the center of the white region.

Comment: @fmw42 I was looking forward to this +1

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1: **How do I replace the cropped box and put back a clear text box?**

After cropping out the box, fill it up with:

```
cropped.fill(255)
```

That will produce

[image]

## Part 2: **How to create an opencv textbox rectangle with the same size as the cropped box?**

Putting in the text, it's a little more nuance, but the steps are first:

- Create the image with the text in it using `cv2.putText()`
- But there are multiple things that

  - length and font of the text that you want to put in and if they fit in the box
  - location/position to put the text in the box

#### TL;DR

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(textwrap.wrap(translation, width=20)):
    cv2.putText(img=cropped, text=chunk, org=(12, 15+i*10), 
         fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, fontScale=0.3, 
         color=(0, 0, 0),thickness=1)
    im2[y:y + h, x:x + w] = cropped
```

To handle the length of the text, I've to use the Python [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) library to break the string into multiple substrings

Then iterating through the substrings, I `putText` each of the substring into the  `cropped` image.

Finally, replace the portion of the original image with the edited cropped image with the text putted into it like `im2[y:y + h, x:x + w] = cropped`

---

A working example can be found on https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/image-translate