# Opencv-Python, draw text with fontsize in pixels

Tags: python, opencv

In the opencv python, we use fontscale or thickness to show the font size, but if I want my font exactly to be 20px, how can I do that?
How can I change the scale/thickness in a way to compute my desired point size?

```
cv2.putText(img_inpainted,boxes['text'][i],(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(120,145,152),1,2)
```

I want the size of text exactly to be L px. How could I go doing that?

I searched and thought a lot, couldn't find any way

Comment: fond height or width to be 20 px?
What do you mean by ```L```?

Comment: L be a arbitrary pixel length, on which I can use some formula

Comment: besides putText there's a function that gives you the size of text without drawing it. that'll help you find a scale factor for that specific font.

Comment: yes I know that, it was something like, getFontSize? But how would I use the scale factor to get result in pixels?

Comment: `cv.getTextSize("foo", cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, fontScale=1.0, thickness=1) => ((29, 10), 6), 10.0 => ((281, 91), 50), 100.0 => ((2801, 901), 500)` see the pattern? -- so with that you could establish a factor in pixels per "scale", and then you can calculate the `fontScale` for your desired font size in pixels. -- I think I'll turn that into an answer...

Comment: I used cv2.getTextSize() in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73084045/how-to-replace-cropped-rectangle-in-opencv/73084935#73084935. Does that example help you?

Comment: Not sure what your `L` is supposed to measure, but you could maybe just draw your text larger than necessary on a blank/black canvas and then trim the canvas to the edges of the text and resize the result to whatever size you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a roundabout way. First you need to know the size of text for a given arbitrary `fontScale`. Then, assuming the Hershey vector fonts scale linearly, you can calculate desired pixel height into a corresponding `fontScale`.

There exists the function [`cv.getTextSize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga3d2abfcb995fd2db908c8288199dba82) to get you the size of a **not-quite**-bounding box for some given text. It's giving a box including ascenders, but excluding descenders... and the baseline goes lower than any descenders among the regular alphabet. I'm guessing they render the text's actual baseline at the height of the origin, and the extra `baseline` value tells us how much further down the drawn text can go still.

Here's a rough outline because I won't explore the effect of the `thickness` parameter for now, except to assume it's 1.

```py
# calculating a factor here
fontScale = 100
fontFace = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

((fw,fh), baseline) = cv.getTextSize(
    "", fontFace=fontFace, fontScale=fontScale, thickness=1) # empty string is good enough
factor = (fh-1) / fontScale

# using the factor now
text = "Hello, World!"
thickness = 1
height_in_pixels = 30 # or 20, code works either way
fontScale = (height_in_pixels - thickness) / factor
(w,h) = (500, 100)
canvas = np.zeros((h, w), 'uint8')
# I'm gonna center it
((fw, fh), baseline) = cv.getTextSize(
    text=text, fontFace=fontFace, fontScale=fontScale, thickness=thickness)
org = ((w-fw)//2, (h+fh)//2)
cv.putText(
    img=canvas, text=text, org=org,
    fontFace=fontFace, fontScale=fontScale, color=255, thickness=thickness)
```

[image: that ought to be 30 pixels]

```
cv.rectangle(canvas, org, (org[0] + fw, org[1] - fh), 128)
cv.line(canvas, (org[0], org[1]+baseline), (org[0] + fw, org[1]+baseline), 128)
```

[image: same with "bounding box" and baseline]

Comment: " if I want my font exactly to be 20px, how can I do that? "

Comment: yeah I picked 30 pixels so the pictures don't look to small. I trust OP to be able to adjust that value. what's your point?